# JavaFX: Error-logging ChangeListener

Tags: java, oop, javafx, lambda

I would like to generalize the following pattern:

```
setChangeListener = c -> {
    try {
    // do something dangerous
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
};
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
errorLoggingSetChangeListener = c -> {
    // do something dangerous
};
```

I was thinking about this:

```
public class ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<T> implements SetChangeListener<T> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener.class);
    private final SetChangeListener<T> delegate;

    @Override
    public void onChanged(final SetChangeListener.Change<? extends T> change) {
    try {
        delegate.onChanged(change);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        if (logger.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    }

    public ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener(final SetChangeListener<T> delegate) {
    super();
    this.delegate = delegate;
    }
}
```

But that is not possible, since ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener is not a Functional interface.

Any chance to convert this class to an Functional Interface?

This does not compile:

```
public interface ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<T> extends SetChangeListener<T> {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener.class);

    @Override
    default void onChanged(final SetChangeListener.Change<? extends T> change) {
    try {
        SetChangeListener.super.onChanged(change);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        if (logger.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This does also not compile:

```
errorLoggingSetChangeListener = new ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<>(c -> {
      throw new IOException();
    });
```

The error message is

> Unhandled exception [..]

.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, you try to call a not implemented function. Function of super is not implemented, since you override it. You provide only 1 function for the interface, but try it to use it 2 times...

Comment: @JohnnyAW agreed. How to fix this?

Comment: there is no way you could use it the way you would like to use it(in java at least, maybe other languages can do it). Waitö let me think...

Comment: using your `ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener` you could use it as follow: `errorLoggingSetChangeListener = new ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener(c -> {// do something dangerous});`. I think this  would be the only way you could use it...

Comment: Does also not compile, see updated question.

Comment: whats the error-message?

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: wait a second, ill put it into compiler...

Comment: I got no compile errors... You need to make sure, that when you override `onChange` that you remove `throws`

Comment: I am not sure. in the example above the exception is thrown in the delegate changelistener. therefore it needs to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to @JonnyAW's solution, but combines both classes into a single interface:

```
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<E> extends SetChangeListener<E> {


    public void delegate(Change<? extends E> change) throws Exception ;

    @Override
    public default void onChanged(Change<? extends E> change) {
        try {
            delegate(change);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // just do a System.out.println here to demo we reach this block:
            System.out.println("Custom error handling...");
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a demo of using this:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableSet<String> set = FXCollections.observableSet();
        ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<String> listener = c -> {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(c.getElementAdded());
                System.out.println("Value added: "+i);
            }
        };
        set.addListener(listener);

        set.add("42");
        set.add("What do you get when you multiply 6 by 9?");
    }

}
```

which generates the expected output:

```
Value added: 42
Custom error handling...
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "What do you get when you multiply 6 by 9?"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Test.lambda$0(Test.java:10)
    at ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener.onChanged(ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.SetListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(SetListenerHelper.java:163)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.SetListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(SetListenerHelper.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableSetWrapper.callObservers(ObservableSetWrapper.java:128)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableSetWrapper.add(ObservableSetWrapper.java:269)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Comment: I like this solution more, since The `DangerousInterface` depends on `SetChangeListener.Change` but seems not to be connected to a Set or the `SetChangeListener` in general. This one looks perfectly clean, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is my implementation, that will compile:

ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener:

```
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;

public class ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<T> implements SetChangeListener<T> {

    private DangerousInterface<T> delegate;

    public ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener(DangerousInterface<T> delegate) {
        super();
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends T> change) {
        try {
            this.delegate.delegate(change);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

DangerousInterface:

```
public interface DangerousInterface<T> {

    public void delegate(Change<? extends T> change) throws Exception;
}
```

Main:

```
SetChangeListener<String> listener = new ErrorLoggingSetChangeListener<>((test) -> {
        //no errors here now
        throw new Exception();
    });
```

I got definitely no compile errors

EDIT: ok, I got the Problem, you need a new Interface that can actually throw something, now you can wrap it in `onChanged`

Comment: You declared your own type `SetChangeListener`. Try to use `javafx.collections.SetChangeListener`.

Comment: this shouldn't make a difference, but ill try, wait a second

Comment: The difference is that this onChange method does not throw Exception ;)

Comment: like I said, no difference, no errors for me. Can you post your code in the current state?

Comment: wait a second, could it be, that your logger is throwing something?

Comment: Think about it. The lambda you are defining in the constructor is the nested  change listener. And this one can not throw any exceptions.